# symfony force format number 4 digits

Tags: php, symfony

how can i force format number 4 digits with symfony.

if I have :
$num = 1;

I need to have 
$num = 0001;

I find a solution with php but cannot work with symfony 
printf("%04d", $num);

Thanks

Comment: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/format.html#format

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I get the solution :
$num = 1;
sprintf('%04d',$num);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
str_pad($num, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

?